# Merge two or more []map[string]interface{} types into one in Golang

Tags: arrays, go, types, maps

I'm using Golang and for some reason, I need to merge results from different database queries, all of which return me a `[]map[string]interface{}`
I'm thinking of Append but its just not clear enough if this is even possible.
What is the final datatype I'm looking at?

Clearly, an array of maps of interfaces with keys as strings should be able to simply 'attach' (concat, if you may) to another array of maps of interfaces with keys as strings!

So what is the mechanism to achieve this?

Comment: well, you could iterate: `for k, v := range(map1) { map2[k] = v}` but you need to decide what happens when there is a key collision. you can check that with `v, ok := map2[k]; if !ok {...}`

Comment: sorry I missed the slice. You can do `newslice := append(slice1, slice2...)` see https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_10.

Comment: Sure you can append just result := append(result1, result2...) if results are of the same type []map[string]interface{}

Comment: You're right. I just gave it a try with what @Uvelichitel said and had to do it twice (because I had 3 arrays) and it worked like a charm!
Should I put it up as an answer?

Comment: Actually the question should be re-written to match go's syntax and ability. For the question and for go it is insignificant that there is a map contained in the slice. You can do the same with any slice type, for example `[]byte`. That's what go's internal function `append` is for and that's how it is documented (append and copy for slices).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even the answer is already given in the comments above i will post a short example how this can be achieved.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    result := []map[string]interface{}{}

    mp1 := map[string]interface{}{
        "one" : 1, 
        "two" : 2,
    }

    mp2 := map[string]interface{}{
        "three" : 3,
        "four" : 4,
    }

    mp3 := make(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range mp1 {
        if _, ok := mp1[k]; ok {
            mp3[k] = v          
        }
    }

    for k, v := range mp2 {
        if _, ok := mp2[k]; ok {
            mp3[k] = v
        }
    }

    result = append(result, mp1, mp2)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

The output will be:

```
[map[one:1 two:2] map[three:3 four:4]]
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/CtLqM8c1lu)

Comment: Kudos! In my case, I had map1, map2 and map3 all of []map[string]interface{} types and I did -

result := map1
result = append(result, map2...)
result = append(result, map3...)

And that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 13):

The other answer is correct. You could also write a helper function to avoid repetitive map merges.

```
// overwriting duplicate keys, you should handle that if there is a need
func mergeMaps(maps ...map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    result := make(map[string]interface{})
    for _, m := range maps {
        for k, v := range m {
            result[k] = v
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    log.Println(`started`)

    v := []map[string]interface{}{
        map[string]interface{}{
            `one`: 1,
            `two`: 2,
        },
        map[string]interface{}{
            `one`:   `I`,
            `three`: 3,
            `other`: `NAN`,
        },
        map[string]interface{}{
            `name`: `Bob`,
            `age`:  300,
        },
    }

    m := mergeMaps(v...)
    log.Println(m, len(m))
}
```

Comment: Makes sense and its useful in the long run! Thank you!

Comment: Note that this is a completely different type of operation! `append` operates on slices. If you merge two maps you can define two different merge operations (`A := A MERGE B`) where B[k] overwrites A[k] and another one where A[k] preserves its values over B[k].

Comment: True, that's why this answer begins with "The other answer is correct". Though other than handling json (or some external data stream), it's some common mistake to have a "slice of maps", and `mp3` is not actually used anywhere inside first answer.

Comment: Personally, I prefer your solution, because in my use case, I actually wish subsequent maps (used to store all sorts of configuration variables, coming from several sources) to override 'default' configurations stored on the first map. This works flawlessly for that kind of usage! Thanks 

Comment: ... actually, I have found an even more interesting suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325337/1035977 Note how it relies on `append()` to do the heavy-duty memory allocations as needed, as opposed to using `make`. I guess it's just a question of choice/preference, both will need the garbage collector to have some fun at the end...

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions suggested by [Endre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211175/endre-simo) and [Kaveh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54467/kaveh-shahbazian) both works, but it is much simpler, handy, and more optimized to use [mergo](https://github.com/imdario/mergo) when one wants to merge Go structs and maps which covers vast scenarios apart from merging map[string]interface{}

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/imdario/mergo"
)

func main() {
    mp1 := map[string]interface{}{
        "one" : 1, 
        "two" : 2,
    }

    mp2 := map[string]interface{}{
        "three" : 3,
        "four" : 4,
    }

    mergo.Merge(&mp1, mp2) //mergo.Merge(&dest,src)
   
    fmt.Println(mp1)
}
```

Output:

```
map[four:4 one:1 three:3 two:2]
```

[image: Go Playground]

P.S. - In Golang there is no order-preserving. Actually, iterating a map in Go is always in random order. So don't rely on a map's keys order.